# Change Power Query from Import to Direct Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, directquery

For some reason I have in a PowerBi dashboard multiple queries that were switched to `import` mode rather than `direct query`.

Is there a way to set an existing query to `direct query` without recreating the query as new one?`

Is there a way to define a blank query as `direct query`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing from direct query to import is one way only. You can't change from import to direct query, more details as the [MS Docs site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-storage-mode)
The site states:

> Changing the Storage mode of a table to Import is an irreversible
> operation. Once set, this property can't later be changed to either
> DirectQuery or Dual.

You'll have to recreate the query or at least the connection and copy the steps over.
You can't create a blank query at import or direct query, you'll have to have some sort of connection it it to define the type.